# Remote stop of process

Tags: powershell-remoting

Our users need access to a server to be able to restart applications, but due to new security policies, they are no longer able to access the server.
Is there a way I can get them to remotely stop the process?
Maybe a shortcut that runs a script as an administrator to stop the application?
The application does not run as a service, I was thinking to do similar to a taskkill.

Also, there are 8 processes running under the same name, how do I know which is which?
They are started in Netlauncher with a startup string that looks something like this:

add key="file005" value="FPCALC 01:-:P:\FLTCTRL\BIN\fpcalc32.exe :-:N CALCPPPCAANZPDDZ FLTCTRL P FCFPFLFNAE YYY 01:-:D:\FLTCTRL\CALC1\FLTCTRL:-:Normal"

Is there any way to show which one is running (e.g. FPCALC01).

Comment: Talk to your superiors and tell them that the new security policies stop people from being able to do their job.